# How to replay a subscriber in RxJava 2?

Tags: rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am searching for a way in rxJava2 where i can call a subscriber again once an action is performed. Let me specifically describe my intention.

I am using retrofit2 for networking but that does not matter. this question is about rxJava. I would like to retry an api call once I refresh a token. What I need to set up is each time I make any api call, the token can expire and its my duty to call another api call to refresh the token. After the token
is refreshed I need to **call again** the same api call that had the expired token. So to the user its seamlessly refreshes the token.

Here is my default subscribe I use for all network calls:

```
public class DefaultSubscriber<T> implements Observer<T> {

    Disposable disposable;

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
        Timber.d("subscribing called now ...");
        disposable = d;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(@NonNull T t) {
        Timber.d("onNext called now ..."+t);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
        Timber.e(e);
        Timber.d("onError called now ...");
        if (e instanceof HttpException) {
            //todo analytics can go here
            // We had non-2XX http error
            HttpException exception = (HttpException) e;
            if (exception.code() == 401){
              //token expired here, handle it
              //so i'll call another api here (to refresh token)but then i need to replay this subscriber , how ?
            }

        }
        if (e instanceof IOException) {
            // A network or conversion error happened
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        Timber.d("onComplete called now ...");
    }

    public void unsubscribe() {
        Timber.d("Un-subscribed called now ..");
        if (disposable != null && !disposable.isDisposed()) {
            disposable.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't there any way to replay a subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `retryWhen()` operator to resubscribe.

```
networkApiObservable
  .retryWhen( errorObservable -> 
    errorObservable.flatMap( error ->
     {
       if ( error.equals(EXPIRED_API_TOKEN) ) {
         return getNetworkApiTokenObservable();
       }
       return Observable.error( error );
     }
  .subscribe();
```

I will assume that `getNetworkApiTokenObservable()` returns an observable that emits when a new API token is available to the `networkApiObservable` source.